# Errors when importing SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

When I import SimpleAudioEngine.h:

```
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

I get six errors.
3 of them are related to CVPixelBuffer.h and 3 are related to CMFormatDescription.h.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of cocs2d are you using?  I would suggest you reinstall the codebase and then see if you get the error.  I use SimpleAudioEngine.h in a few games and have not seen an error simply by including the .h file.

Also check if you have the AudioToolbox.framework